# What difference does it make when I include <limits> or <limits.h> in my c++ code

Tags: c++, header-files

Can somebody please explain this?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <limits.h>
```

or

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <limits>
```

Comment: `<limits>` and `<limits.h>` are different, one is for c++, the other is for c

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Don't add unrealated tags.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`<limits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/limits) is a C++ Standard Library header providing similar insights to the C header `<limits.h>` (which is also available in C++ as [`<climits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/climits)), but it is written in a way that's more useful and safe in C++ programs:

- say you have a `template <typename Numeric> ...`, and the code inside wants to know the minimum and maximum value of the `Numeric` type parameter that the user instantiated your template with: you can use `std::numeric_limits<Numeric>::min()` and `...::max()`; if you wanted to access the same values from `<climits>`, it'd be hard to know which of `SCHAR_MIN`, `SHRT_MIN`, `INT_MIN`, `LONG_MIN` etc. to use and you'd have to switch between them all yourself - lots of extra code for something so trivial
- `<climits>` has lots of macros, and macros don't respect namespaces or scopes the way "normal" C++ identifiers do - their substitutions are made pretty indiscriminately - so they make your program more error prone
- `<limits>` gives much more insight about numeric types, such as whether they're signed, the number of base-10 digits they can handle, whether they can represent infinity or not-a-number sentinel values etc. (see the [header docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/limits) for a fuller list and information)

Comment: You also need `<cfloat>` to match the full range of `<limits>`.

Answer (score 2):

`limits.h` is a C standard library header. `limits` is a C++ standard library header. They contain [different](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/limits) things.

There is `climits` in C++, which offers [more or less what `limits.h` did](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/climits).

Comment: `limits.h` is required in standard C++.